# Java кодировка кириллицы в Swing UI

Tags: java, кодировка, swing, кириллица

В Intellij Idea при запуске приложения и нажатия на кнопку Translate в интерфейсе происходит перевод английского заголовка на русский посредством отображения в textArea. Кириллица отображается корректно. Однако когда приложение собрано в jar и запускается из него, то кириллица превращается в иероглифы. По некоторым советам я менял кодировку в pom.xml, но это не помогло.

Все исходники здесь https://github.com/mrprogre/avandy-news

в pom.xml такая часть в настройках:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Вот процедура перевода:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Translator {

public String translate(String langFrom, String langTo, String text) {
    StringBuilder response;
    String scriptUrl = Common.SCRIPT_URL;
    try {
        String urlStr = scriptUrl +
                "?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8") +
                "&target=" + langTo +
                "&source=" + langFrom;
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        response = new StringBuilder();
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return response.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: вы используете системные  шрифты  или  какие-то  кастомные? ТОчно  иероглифы  или  вопросики  и  квадратики?

Comment: Шрифт "Tahoma".. вот как переводит новость "Mexico Congress votes to keep military on streets" = 
РљРѕРЅРіСЂРµСЃСЃ РњРµРєСЃРёРєРё РїСЂРѕРіРѕР»РѕСЃРѕРІР°Р» Р·Р° СЃРѕС…СЂР°РЅРµРЅРёРµ РІРѕРµРЅРЅС‹С… РЅР° СѓР»РёС†Р°С…

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())` на `new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")`. По умолчанию `InputStreamReader` использует системную кодировку.

Comment: Да, помогло! Спасибо! Напишите это как ответ, приму, т.к. много чего читал, а такого очевидного, когда уже знаешь ответ, момента никто не указал!

Comment: Ок. Оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию `InputStreamReader` использует системную кодировку. Это не самое удачное решение от разработчиков Java API, поскольку работа программы начинает зависеть не только от ОС, но и от способа запуска в рамках одной ОС (как в этом случае).

Поэтому лучше всегда явно указывать кодировку при создании экземпляра `InputStreamReader`.

В данном вопросе нужно заменить `new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())` на `new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")`.